# Sync Codes in R Studio while working with multiple machines

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to synchronize all my codes in order to access it on different machines.

Is there any way around, kindly help.

Thank You

Comment: Use Git and Github repositories?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for suggestion, i was looking some other way of doing it without Git.